# Normalize by squishing/stretching data between -1 and 1

Tags: matlab

The code below will normalize a vector that has both positive and negative values to a a range of [-1,1]. However, if you look at the plot you will notice that the plot is shifted downward due to the type of normalization.

**Question:**

Is there a way to alter the method to normalize the data between -1 and 1 without shifting the data?

```
%# generate some vector
vec = [0,0.5,0.8660254040,.8,0.866025404,0.5,1.22E-16,-0.1,-0.4,-0.3, ...
-0.6,-0.5,-2.45E-16,0.5,0.866025404,1.3,0.866025404,0.5,3.67E-16, ...
-0.5,-0.4,-0.7,-0.7,-0.5,-4.90E-16];

%# get max and min
maxVec = max(vec);
minVec = min(vec);

%# normalize to -1...1
vecN = ((vec-minVec)./(maxVec-minVec) - 0.5 ) *2;

% plot results
plot(vec,'k'); hold on;
plot(vecN,'--r'); hold off;
```

**Plot of original vector (black) vs normalized vector (red dashed)**

This behavior normalized the vector but shifts the plot which is not desired.

[image: Plot of original vector (black) vs normalized vector (red dashed)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above answer by Ander got me thinking that to perform the action I was trying to get at it would best to treat positive and negative values separately and then merge the results from the "normalized" squished/stretched result.

The function below squishes or stretches the input vector as needed between -1 and 1 creating a type of "normalization".

**Code**

```
function [vecN] = normSquish(vec)
% Returns a "squished" normalized vector (vecN).
% The function squishes/stretches the positive/negative relative to the
% max/min of vec.

%% Normalize input vector
% get max and min
maxVec = max(vec);
minVec = min(vec);

vecPos = vec;
vecNeg = vec;
vecPos(vecPos<0) = 0;
vecNeg(vecNeg>0) = 0;

vecPosN = vecPos./abs(maxVec);
vecNegN = vecNeg./abs(minVec);

vecN = vecPosN;
zs = find(vecPos==0);
for i = 1:size(zs,2)
    index = zs(i);
    vecN(index)=vecNegN(index);
end
```

**Plot comparing original methods and proposed solutions**
[image: Comparison of methods]

Comment: This also changes the mean, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes it does. I used "mean" for lack of a better word and tried to make it better by saying "relative mean". Clearly it wasn't very effective. Forgive the confusion. I was trying to get at the fact that I wanted a method that didn't shift the data at zero.

Answer (score 4):

If you normalize to your data to be between -1 and 1 then surely the data will change, thus the mean. If you "normalize" you can not avoid that.

Instead, scale the data to be within the range you desire:

`vecN=vec*1/max(abs(max(vec)),abs(min(vec)));`

The mean **will** change though, whenever you change the data. This way is just easier to retrieve (`mean(vec)==mean(vecN)*max(abs(max(vec)),abs(min(vec)))`)

Comment: Thanks for your input. The solution you provided wasn't quite what I was trying to describe. Clearly the mean does change. I tried to describe what I meant by saying "relative mean". But lost in translation you know? Your answer got me thinking along a different track though so I was able to get the solution I was looking for. +1 for your help!